# SQLALchemy: Query a single key or subset of keys of a Postgres JSONB column

Tags: python, json, postgresql, orm, sqlalchemy

I have a Postgres table that has a JSONB column. How do I query data of this column without loading the whole column at once in SQLAlchemy?

Let's say the JSONB column `myjsonb` contains `{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, ... 'z': 26}`. I only want the value of `'a'` and not all 26 values. How do I specify a query to do that?

For example,

```
query = session.query(MyTable).options(defer('myjsonb')).join(MyTable.myjsonb['a'])
```

does not work.

Any idea how I can only retrieve `'a'`? And what happens if the key `'a'` is not present? And how can I load multiple keys, let's say `'b'` to '`f'`, but not all of them at once? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually pretty straight forward, you just query for the keys you are interested as in:

```
query = session.query(MyTable.myjsonb['a'])
```

If you want multiple keys from the json object, lets say `a` and `c`, you do

```
query = session.query(MyTable.myjsonb['a'], MyTable.myjsonb['c'])
```

If any of the keys are not present, it will just return `None` for that row.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, I either get:
`NotImplementedError: Operator 'getitem' is not supported on this expression`

or 

`AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'measurements'` if I do `MyTable.__table__.myjsonb['a']`

Comment: duh, I was using [jsonfield](https://github.com/penguinolog/sqlalchemy_jsonfield) to allow json in our dev sqlite db. Removing this and everything works as expected. Thanks!